# Can I run multiple instances of an azure function listening to the same queue

Tags: azure, azure-functions

**Background:**
I have been running into an issue recently that my function can not handle the load and the queue messages are building up.  In the long term I am looking at the code to find where there are bottle necks but in the short term I need to solve this problem.
**Question:**
**Can I add multiple instances of the same azure function (even if it is a rename myjobrunner1, myjobrunner2) etc that all listen to the same queue?  Would this help in my situation?**

**Some caveats:**
The premium plan looks good but I can not test a preview while in production at the moment.
Adding a dedicated AppService is an option but it is a longer term fix.  I am having the trouble now.
Code fixes are in process to handle the load better and improve performance but the fact that the outside services are what is holding them up is a factor.

Comment: What kind of tier/plan are you currently using? If you add another function, I'm not 100% certain how things would behave, but I'd probably expect to see some processing of the same message multiple times, which would make me not want to go for it. I think opting for a higher-usage tiered plan would be the safest best, and let Azure determine how many instances it needs to run based on the queue. We use a consumption plan and it scales out nicely when we sync data hourly, and then the bottleneck becomes Cosmos DB

Comment: I thought that the azure functions would scale out better personally.   That seemed to be the promise but my queue keeps building up.  There really is no time for the VM to dissappear because it looks to be running at capacity.  I don't have an issue with paying double for my current consumption plan (or triple) if it would work. But I always thought that the idea with a queue was once a message was off it nothing else could get it.

Answer (score 0):

How I solved the problem.
I added an additional queue and logic to split the messages between the two queues. I then created a new instance of the function (1 and 2) which pointed to the second queue.  I originally thought that queues worked by allowing only one copy of the message to be pulled off.  Then no other service could read that message.  This does not seem to be the case with my testing.

Running two functions each with the max batch count solved the problem.  It is a pattern I can continue until we can effectively look at more code enhancements.  But our bottle neck seems to be the httpclient instances (I cant run them as static and would require significant changes) and some db calls that could be optimized.

If someone else has another suggestion please add it.
When premium plan goes to release I will try that but until then I will have to stick with this solution.